# How do I implement Ctrl+Z / Command+Z in Java/Swing?

Tags: java, swing, hotkeys

I'm working on a little Java applet that needs undo/redo functionality.  Here's code to set up the hotkeys (works great on Windows).

My question is: how do I make it use command+Z on mac?  Should I just check System.getProperty("os.name") or is there a more elegant alternative??

```
private void setupUndoHotkeys() {
    String UNDO = "Undo action key";
    String REDO = "Redo action key";
    Action undoAction = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            undo();
        }
    };
    Action redoAction = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            redo();
        }
    };

    getActionMap().put(UNDO, undoAction);
    getActionMap().put(REDO, redoAction);

    InputMap[] inputMaps = new InputMap[] {
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED),
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT),
        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW),
    };
    for(InputMap i : inputMaps) {
        i.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Z"), UNDO);
        i.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control Y"), REDO);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Neal

Comment: I love that I was able to paste your code directly into my own without needing to change anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah nevermind, I found it [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-program-apple-command-key-keystroke-java-swing-mac-osx)

This should undo on any platform.

```java
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx());
```

Parsing it through `setAccelerator()` would set <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> as its shortcut. 
(Most swing components have this method.)

Comment: This works for Undo (ctrl-Z vs. cmd-Z), but NOT for Redo (ctrl-Y vs Shift-cmd-Z). I'm worried os.name is needed for Redo key stroke.

Comment: @ChristopherBruns I'm afraid you're right.  If it's any comfort, Microsoft Office Mac used Cmd+Y until 2011.

Comment: The above code is deprecated is there another working alternative?

Comment: @219CID I Have updated to the latest current alternative.