# How to capture Command Z KeyStroke on Mac in Java

Tags: java, macos, swing

I am currently able to capture ctrl + z keystroke on Mac using the below code.

```
public void registerUndoAction(ControlPane controlPane) {
        ActionMap map = this.getActionMap();
        Action action = controlPane.undoAction();

        String keyStrokeAndKey = "control Z";
        KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStrokeAndKey);
        this.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyStrokeAndKey);
        this.getActionMap().put(keyStrokeAndKey, action);
    }
```

which works fine. However, I think it is more natural when on a Mac to use the "command + z" key stroke combination as opposed to "ctrl + z".

I have tried to capture this key stroke by using this instead:

```
    String keyStrokeAndKey = "command Z";
```

however this doesn't work. No action is registered when I use the above snippet to capture this key stroke. I tried following this similar question: [How do I implement Ctrl+Z / Command+Z in Java/Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465869/how-do-i-implement-ctrlz-commandz-in-java-swing)

But the code referenced in that question did not register my "command + z" key strokes. And additionally, my IDE gave warnings that:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()
```

is deprecated (the original question is 10 years old). So is there a key stroke for command z? If not, what is the alternative to capture this action. Thanks!

Comment: There is now [getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getMenuShortcutKeyMaskEx()); that is why the other is deprecated.

Comment: `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, KeyEvent.META_DOWN_MASK)` will get you `KeyStroke` you need for MacOS - you may need to verify how that works on Windows and adjust you bindings accordingly